# Is there a way to download only the Rest API part of WordPress?

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

Is there a way of downloading only the `Rest API` part of WordPress and not all the old PHP files?

Comment: question as is do not make much sense. API is just a definition of what functions names to use and what parameters they can recieve. You can not "download" an API, a best you can download a documentation of it.

Comment: WordPress’s Rest API is hosted in your website and not on Wordpress.org or Wordpress.com so you need to download it. Right? Am I wrong?

Comment: You can't host an API, you can host the code that implements it. The code that implements the wordpress rest API is part of wordpress

Comment: Hadn't thought about it that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP REST API depends on WordPress, as it is just another interface for interacting with its other APIs. If BackPress (https://backpress.org/) was still in development, you could have had some chance with it, but it seems the project is abandoned.

The plugin that was merged with WordPress Core is available here: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API but is also abandoned, so you will not get the latest stuff that's in 5.8. I don't know whether this would be of help to you, as I don't know your main goal, but I would rather try to extract whatever I need from nowadays' Core, than messing with the old plugin.

Comment: I though that Rest API used only JS and I did not need any of the PHP files. So I just din't want to have toooons of unused files. But since the "unused" files are actualy used I will hust continue with the normal WordPress

Comment: In the future WordPress will have a modern only JS version rigth?

Comment: No, it won’t. The REST API is powered entirely by PHP anyway. It just means that you can write a JS application that uses WordPress data. WordPress itself is not going to be JS.

Comment:  Thanks for your answers!!